# Marking multiple lines in ed

Tags: gnu, ed

I've opened ed and inserted the following text:

```
This text
Is a
Test
```

However, when I attempt to mark lines 1-3 using the following command:

```
1,3ki
```

And print them with

```
'ip
```

It only prints the *last occurence*. Is there a way I can mark all three line (i.e. `1,3`)? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

One label can only mark a single line.  If you give a range of lines to the `k` command, only the last entered address will be marked since the `k` command only takes a single address.

This is from [the `ed` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) in the POSIX standard (my emphasis):

> If more than the required number of addresses are provided to a command that requires zero addresses, it shall be an error. Otherwise, if more than the required number of addresses are provided to a command, **the addresses specified first shall be evaluated and then discarded until the maximum number of valid addresses remain**, for the specified command.

The `k` command looks like `(.)kx` in the standard, which means it takes at most one address (defaulting to the current line).

Depending on what the effect is that you want to achieve, you could use two labels, one for line 1 and another one for line 3, or you could use your single label together with an address relative to that label with the `p` command.

So, either use two labels,

```
1ka
3kb
'a,'b p
```

or use a single label and relative addressing when you call `p`,

```
1ka
'a,'a+2 p
```

or

```
3kb
'b-2,'b p
```

or something like

```
3kb
'b; -2,. p
```

or

```
1ka
'a; .,+2 p
```

Comment: I was hoping to use `k` in conjunction with 'g' to select multiple lines, then perform an operation on _all_ of them. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Perhaps I can make `.` select multiple lines... Is this achievable in vanilla `ed`?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser It's a bit unclear what you want to do. If you want to apply a command on a number of lines, can't you use the `g` command to do that directly instead of trying to mark them up? Of course you can use the `k` command with `g`, but you'd be moving a single mark around on individual lines. A label set with `k` can only be set to a single line.  The `.` address always addresses the current line.

Comment: According to the POSIX standard, "In the g command, the first step shall be to mark every line for which the line excluding the terminating <newline> matches the given RE." Could this be achieved inside the editor?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser `g/RE/ kx` would mark each line that matches `RE`. The `x` mark would be applied to the first such line, then to the second, and so on. In the end, the last line matching `RE` will be marked with `x`.  Each time the `kx` command is executed, the `x` mark is moved to the current line.  A label can only ever be applied to a single line. Applying it to a second line moves it to that line.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser Within the `g` command, you could use `'x` and it would refer to the current line.  See e.g. the effect of ``g/RE/kx\`` followed by `'x` on a new line.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser It is still unclear what it is you are trying to achieve. A label can only ever be associated with a single line.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser If you want to execute something for every line matching a regular expression, you could just use the `g` command. `k` would probably not be very useful.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood the scope of the `k` and `g` commands. I'd like to run multiple commands without re-typing addresses. VIM does this by allowing the user to select lines, then run multiple commands on the selected lines. E.g. `y`, `d`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser The `k` command to mark a line is nothing like Vim's or Vi's "yank".  Both those editors _also_ implement the `k` command. `ed` also does not implement "movement commands" like `d}` etc. To delete a number of lines, use e.g. `2,5 d` (for a continuous range between line 2 and 5 inclusively) or `g/RE/ d` (deletes every line that matches `RE`), or something like `.,/^$/ d` to delete from here to the end of the paragraph (approximately).

Comment: I wasn't comparing `k` and visual mode; I was simply referring to VI's method of performing multiple operations on one piece of text. Perhaps I should've titled this question "SEd -e equivalent in Ed"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129329/discussion-between-stackoverflowuser-and-kusalananda).